# PHP file_exists function is always returning false

Tags: php

This code that is meant to check if a file exists is always returning false;

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $page = $_GET['p'];
}
else {
    $page = "home";
}
$JKSP = '/Pages/JKS-' . $page . '.php';
if (!file_exists($JKSP)) {
    $JKSP = '/Pages/JKS-404.php';
}
?>
```

It works fine without the if (!file_ex..  section.

How can I get this code to work?

The directory of this code is 
/featured/JksCreations/
The directory of the pages is
/featured/JksCreations/Pages/JKS- *PAGE* .php

Comment: Try to put a dote before your first slash, does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Perhaps you should be checking for a __relative__ filepath rather than an __absolute__ one

Comment: @AustinCollins Glad I could help you. (Added an answer where I explained it a bit more)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish in the end, but `file_exists()` generally checks an absolute path in the root filesystem of the machine the webserver is running on, while you seem to try to check a path relative to the root directoty of the webserver (which is a subdirectory of the root filesystem).

You can access this subdirectory in PHP using the predefined variable [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

So something like

```
if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/featured/JksCreations" . $JKSP)) {
    $JKSP = '/Pages/JKS-404.php';
}
```

might work for what you try to do, but it might also still fail due to missing permissions.

Also, be careful what you do with your result, especially in an untrusted environment. You should check that the parameter `p` only consists of valid characters for a filename (especially no dots and slashes).

Comment: Thank you, however this did not work for me. Also I know of the issues with /../ I have fixed this by forcing a unique suffix onto the file name: $JKSP = './Pages/' . $page . '-JKS.php';

Answer (score 0):

So what you did is you checked with an **absolute** path, but you want to check with a **relative** path, so you have to put a dot before your fist slash to make it relative from your current path, like this:

```
$JKSP = './Pages/JKS-' . $page . '.php';
       //^ See here
```